# Apache Ignite Partitioned Mode with 1 backup copy: updates to cache do not get reflected in both paritions?

Tags: ignite

I have an Apache Ignite cluster with 5 nodes, running in PARTITIONED mode with 1 back-up copy for each primary partition (also configured to read from backup if it's on the local node).

Updates to data in one of the caches is received from a Kafka topic, updates are processed and cache is re-loaded as required.

However, occasionally, I am observing that when I request the data from the cache, I will get the correct updated data a handful of times, but this will alternate with getting the stale data pre-update back.

It seems to me that something fails when syncing between the primary and back up node upon update (configuration is FULL_SYNC so not related to async issues). I can't spot any errors in the logs which suggest something like this however.

How can I determine if this is the cause of the issue? What else may be going wrong to cause this behaviour?

Running on Ignite 2.9.1

Thanks

Comment: Simplify the use case. Remove all other services, and create a cluster w/one node. Make the kafka updater run on a set interval, and a corresponding service that get the data once it gets updated. See if the error is reproduced. Can extract a pattern from the data? Vary the pattern if need be.  Add a second node and repeat the experiment.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Will give it a try today

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598175/ignite-read-stale-data-from-backup-node. Perhaps `readFromBackup` causes the issue?

Comment: thanks @StanislavLukyanov - that seems to be the case. I was just under the impression that when you have configure the cache write synchronisation to FULL_SYNC this cannot happen