# Ignite read stale data from backup node

Tags: backup, cluster-computing, ignite

I ran into in-consistency data issues on ignite version 2.8.1. I have three nodes run as a cluster and the cache configuration as:

```
    CacheConfiguration<String, Balance> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>(Balance.class.getSimpleName());
    cacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(String.class, Balance.class);
    cacheConfiguration.setSqlIndexMaxInlineSize(100);
    cacheConfiguration.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
    cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
    cacheConfiguration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    cacheConfiguration.setBackups(4);
    cacheConfiguration.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
```

Then I have very simple code to add balance in a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    balance = balanceDao.findByKey(accountId, "USD");
    balance.setQuantity(balance.getQuantity().add(BigDecimal.ONE));
    balanceDao.save(balance);
}
```

when run above on the primary node, I always have balance increased 10000 correctly, however when run that on backup node, sometimes my balance increased around 8k, and sometimes 9k.

if setWriteSynchronizationMode was set to PRIMARY_SYNC and setReadFromBackup was set to false, I can get correct balance on all nodes.

is this a bug on 2.8.1 or anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Can you throw together a reproducer project, share it via github or zip? I will check it.

Comment: Hi alamar, sorry I was trying these two days but failed to re-create. I ran into the issue on 2.8.1 weeks ago and then upgrade to 2.9.1 and run the same test case without issue. I thought the issue was fixed on version 2.9.1, however sometimes I still found the mismatch (twice in the past week), the issue for me is on prod, it's quite annoying. really appreciate some advise. Thanks

Comment: Without a reproducer it's hard to say what happens here.

Comment: understand, thanks. should I change the mode to PRIMARY_SYNC and disable reading from backup? what is the difference from the settings I have now, and will that add any network latency when read data?

Comment: You can try that, I guess. Reads will have extra latency but writes slightly less.

Answer (score 0):

If `readFromBackup == true` (which is the default), it is possible to read stale values on the backup nodes. Set it to `false` to avoid stale reads.